# NSSet Enumeration error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset

Sorry for newbie questions, but we all was at this point :)

I'm doing enumeration to get the right object from the NSSet to set the Cell's title to the object from the Set, Here's my code:

```
    // the object we want from the set
MinorGoal *minor = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// enumeration
for (NSManagedObject *minorTwo in minorGoalsSet) {
    if ([minorTwo == minor]) // I get error here: "Expected Identifier"
        cell.textLabel.text = minor.title;


}
```

Well when I run it I get the error: "Expected Identifier" on this line:

```
if ([minorTwo == minor])
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What's the point for enumerating the `minorGoalsSet`? Is it to set the title only when `minor` is present among the `minorGoalsSet`'s elements?

Comment: because I'm using relationships, core-data, and I have minor objects of main objects, I'm fetching all objects in the "fetchedResultsController", and then check if it belongs to the set (when is the main object's minors) @dasblinkenlight

Comment: What about `if([minorGoalsSet containsObject:minor]) ...` ?

Comment: @MartinR that gets me the wrong object. IDK y.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is nonsensical.  If you're trying to compare two objects, you need to send a message:

```
if ([minorTwo isEqual:minor])
```

Or somehing along those lines.  Since they're instances of different classes, that's probably not going to work well for you, though.

Comment: `MinorGoal` is probably a `NSManagedObject` subclass, therefore a simple `if (minorTwo == minor)` might work as well. (The question remains why the enumeration is needed at all.)